# rotate image in ellipse

Tags: android, rotation

How can I rotate a set of images in an ellipse using android animation class.I have used rotate animation class but it is rotating image in the circle format.There is any way we can achieve the rotation of image in ellipse.

Comment: what you mean by rotate a set of image?

Comment: k I want to rotate  a single image .....